# Unable to locate libssh-devel package on Kali 2018.4

Tags: apt, kali-linux

If I try to install libssh-devel or libssh-devel I am unable to locate the package. I have updated and upgraded with apt so that all packages are now up to date, but still just get left with unable to find package.

Comment: `apt-cache search <string>` is your friend

Answer (score 1):

On Kali, like other Debian derivatives, you can use `apt search` to look for packages. `apt search libssh` will tell you that the package containing the development files for `libssh` is `libssh-dev`, so

```
apt install libssh-dev
```

will install the files you need.